# How to use pandas to extract incomplete dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with a "Collection Date" column, in this column most of the dates are written YYYY-MM-DD, for example "2020-03-23", but some entries only have the year (e.g. 2020).

e.g.

```
0             2020
1       2020-03-23
2       2020-12-11
3       2020-04-10
4       2020-04-03
```

I want to find the entries that only have the year and convert them to NaT, so that I can then pull those entries out to a separate file.

I thought I would be able to do this with pandas pd.to_datetime - i've tried the following:

```
df["Collection date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Collection date"], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce', exact=True)
```

However this converts the "2020" entry to 2020-01-01, rather than NaT.  I thought this would work as I've specified the Y-m-d format, and that it must be an exact match, but I'm obviously missing something here.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the "2020" entry replaced with NaT, rather than converted to a date?  2020-01-01 is not the correct date!

Comment: Possible related https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12649. You can do an extra check for the only year situation and mask the result to NaT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace value by length to NaN and convert to datetime after.

Oneliner:

```
import numpy as np
df["Collection Date"] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(df['Collection Date'].str.len()>4, df["Collection Date"], np.nan))
```

which can be split into 2 rows for more readability:

```
import numpy as np
df["Collection Date"] = np.where(df['Collection Date'].str.len()>4, df["Collection Date"], np.nan)
df["Collection Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Collection Date"])
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to convert the column to a string first:  
 
`df["Collection Date"] = df["Collection date"].astype('str')`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to check the length of each value in the date column. If it is equal or less than 4 (len(2020) == 4) then it should be replaced with NaT else the entry is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to pd.NaT by applying a lambda:

```
df["Collection date"] = df["Collection date"].apply(
        lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x if "-" in x else pd.NaT, errors="coerce")
)
```